# How to launch my app from the last activity (save progress)

Tags: android

Hi i'm building a multiple choice story game in java. There are many buttons (options) that lead you into another activity changing the story. Obviously when you close and open the app again you have to start from the first activity. you Know about something that can save the progress (a button with variables) or something else?

Comment: you will need a splash activity for it. Save your last activity in `Preferences` then check in your `splash` activity to move to last saved activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store more variables in android you have to use database. In case, if you want to store one or less amount variables you can use Android - Shared Preferences [enter link description here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)
It won't change value of variable until you reinstall or update the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) for this, everytime the progress is changed update the saved value like this :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("TheFileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("currentStory", currentStory); // store currentStory or currentProgress here
editor.apply();
```

Now when the app opens, you can check what's the current story/ progress, like this:

```
sharedPref.getString("currentStory","");
```

and then open the respective activity according to the progress.

Just in case, if you want to remove any key from `SharedPreferences`, you can simply do :

```
sharedPref.edit().remove("shared_pref_key").commit();
```

or, to clear all the data:

```
sharedPref.edit().clear().commit();
```

You can switch activities in your starting `Activity` like this:

```
String currentStory = sharedPref.getString("currentStory","");

if(currentStory.equals("story1")){
    startActivity(new Intent(...)) // Activity for story1
}else if(currentStory.equals("story2")){
    startActivity(new Intent(...)) // Activity for story2
}
...
# similarly for other stories
```